# Connection to MS SQL Server 2005 database (using Server.MapPath)

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I am tring to make the below application work with SQL Server 2005 Database

Currently it works for test.mdb, which is in the same folder with the application. How shoud I modify the MapPath to work with SQL Server.

```vb
Dim sDSN
' To use a DSN-Less Connection use the following sDSN definition.
' !!! By using this, UTE is able to detect Primary Keys accurately.

sDSN = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &_
    "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("test.mdb")

' To use a DSN (ODBC) Connection use the following sDSN defintion.
' You need to setup an ODBC data source.
' !!! By using this, UTE is *NOT* always able to detect Primary Keys accurately.                                        
' sDSN = "test"

Dim ute
Set ute = new clsUTE

ute.DBName      = "TEST.MDB"  ' Name of Database. For display purpose only
'ute.ReadOnly    = True       ' readonly mode
'ute.ListTables  = False      ' display toolbutton to list all tables within db
'ute.Filters     = False      ' display toolbutton to define and activate filters
'ute.Export      = False      ' display toolbutton to export all data to CSV file
'ute.SQL         = False      ' display toolbutton to show current sql statement
'ute.Definitions = False      ' display toolbutton to show field defintions

ute.Init sDSN   ' init must be called *before* any HTML code is
                ' is written, otherwise the export feature doesn't work !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Server.MapPath to connect to a SQLServer DB, unlike an *.mdb file you are not connecting to an individual file but to a running instance of SqlServer.  See [connectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) for more information.

Your connection string will be something like:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: sDSN = "Data Source=MYSERV\PSAPP01; Initial Catalog=myDB; User Id=exUser; password=exPass" When I make a little change like that, it gives internal server error 500

Comment: Try creating a SqlConnection object using your connection string and calling .Open() on it, this will tell you if your connection string is okay.